# UICollectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method doesn't work in my app. I don't get printed any output with `NSLog`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *imageObject = [self.imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"file"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        }
    }];

    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
    cell.imageView.image = self.image;
    return cell;
}
```

I would like that when I tap on a cell, that take the image selected, and give the image to `self.image`.

Can we make that in segue? Because my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method doesn't work at all.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhotoDetail"]) {
        NSLog(@"SEGUE showPhotoDetail");
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController = (PhotoDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        photoDetailViewController.truckImage = self.image;

    //[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
        NSLog(@"%@", photoDetailViewController.truckImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of your collectionView. Did you set the delegate to self?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method signature of selecting Item is wrong, the correct method signature is this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[More Info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012176-CH1-SW8)

## Edit

try this code to get the selected image.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.image = cell.imageView.image;
}
```

## Edit 2

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhotoDetail"]) {
         // get index path of selected cell
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems objectAtIndex:0];
         // get the cell object
         PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         // get image from selected cell
         self.image = cell.imageView.image;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS !!! :)

Now my didSelectItemAtIndexPath works.
But do you know how to pass the image I've selected from cell to self.image ?

Comment: Perfect, that WORKS !!!
But my didSelectItemAtIndexPath start before my prepareForSegue...
I post my prepareforsegue, I would like that my prepareforsegue starts after my didselectitematindexpath :/ @Yogesh Suthar edited

Comment: @Viny76 I think you need to pass the selected image to next ViewController? If I am right then you don't require `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you need to do this in `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Yes, but how to replace "PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];" in prepareForSegue method ? @Yogesh Suthar

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems objectAtIndex:0]; is not recognize :'(

Look on my screen : http://imageshack.com/a/img849/5152/5kh5.png
@Yogesh Suthar

Comment: @Viny76 `collectionView` means your `UICollectionView` object. may be it is `self.collectionView`.

Comment: That works !!!! Thanks for your patience :)
And with your comments I can understand everything !!! :D